# Loop over a list of strings in python

Tags: python

I need help with my final porgramming project in highschool.

First i save some numbers to a .txt file, and try to read them. But then i get this list:

```
['360\n', '330\n', '482\n']
```

I need a way to remove the "\n", somehow and saving it to a new list so i can make them integers instead of strings.

Here is how i was thinking of doing it (salary.txt is the file were the numbers is saved to)

```
target = open("salary.txt", "r")
time = target.readlines()
for i in time:
    i.replace("\n", "", 1)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable; `.replace()` returns a new copy that which you discard.

Comment: There's this obscure builtin called `int`, maybe give it a try.

Comment: `i.replace(...)` returns a copy of the string and does not mutate the string itself (strings in python are immutable).

Comment: I think you want `new_list = [int(x) for x in old_list]`

Comment: @khelwood `strip` is not even needed.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, just realised. =)

Comment: :slaps: to all the long-time Python users who didn't realise that `int()` ignores leading & trailing whitespace when you feed it a string arg. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove the newline at the end.

```
times = ['360\n', '330\n', '482\n']
int_times = [int(time.strip()) for time in times]
# [360, 330, 482]
```

But actually, you don't need it because `int("3\n")` is already `3`:

```
int_times = [int(time) for time in times]
# [360, 330, 482]
```

It means you could also write:

```
int_times = map(int, times)
```

Comment: I still like map when the callable to be mapped already exists. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
salaries = []
with open("salary.txt") as time:
    for i in time:
        salaries.append( int(i.strip()) )
```